# Move list item up

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello coders i have the following script: http://jsfiddle.net/UqDJk/241/

I want the moveUp function to move the list up one place..

```
var moveUp = function (up, direction) {
  var btn = up.target,
    li = btn.parentNode;

  li.insertBefore(li[1].nextSibling)
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this? P.s. please pure javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
li.parentNode.insertBefore(li, li.previousSibling);
```

But note that `li.previousSibling` will be `null` for the first element, in which case it will *appended* to the list. So you have to add a check to avoid moving the first element:

```
if (li.previsousSibling) {
    li.parentNode.insertBefore(li, li.previousSibling);
}
```

---

Problems in your code:

- DOM manipulation methods always(?) work on the parent node, not on the node itself. If you don't know exactly how a method works, look up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org), e.g. google for `mdn insertBefore`.
- `li[1]` tries to access property `1` of `li`, which does not exist since `li` is a DOM element object.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the `t`, it should be `insertBefore`... you could have figured that out too ;)

Comment: yeah i figure it out sorry!

Comment: so for my move down function it is totaly not the same

Comment: li.parentNode.insertBefore(li, li.nextSibling); // it should be like this right?

Comment: No, if you insert the node *before* its *next* sibling, you are just inserting where it is right now. You want to insert it before the "next next" sibling: `li.parentNode.insertBefore(li, li.nextSibling.nextSibling);`. Of course you should always make sure that `li.nextSibling` is defined.